# emai address naming, оптимизация работы с почтой

Tags: mail.ru

Хочу создать отдельные почтовые аккаунты: для учёбы, для работы, для игр и прочей фигни.
Вопрос в том, как лучше и правильнее их назвать. Особенно это касается рабочего.
Например: {фамилия}.work@mail.ru, {фамилия}.learn@mail.ru, {фамилия}.game@mail.ru
Или лучше сделать один email и как-то его настроить (буду благодарен, если реально полезных ссылок накините). Также есть вопрос по поводу семантики доменов почты, и есть ли она вообще. mail, bk, list, inbox...
Хочу оптимизировать работу с почтой.

Comment: Сейчас там алиасы, кстати, есть. Т.е. в один почтовый акакунт можно получать почту на несколько виртуальных адресов.

Answer (score 1):

Создайте себе Gmail почту. А после используйте алиасы, например вот так:

```
email+game@gmail.com
email+work@gmail.com
```